# Get datetime of LastKnownLocation

Tags: android, locationmanager, android-gps

I think instead of LocationManager you can use FusedLocationProviderClient for getting Latitude, Longitude, Date and time. Here my code

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
private Location lastKnownLocation;
private void getDeviceLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        Task<Location> locationResult = fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation();
        locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
                    lastKnownLocation = task.getResult();
                    if (lastKnownLocation != null) {
                        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                                        lastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                        long time = lastKnownLocation.getTime();
                        Date date = new Date(time);
                        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                        String str=simpleDateFormat.format(date);
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"time: "+str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

This works fine for me. Hope it's helpful if any mistake pls suggest. I've not included the GPS permission code. If you want means I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get please just try to get the time from location object like

```
long time = location.gettime()

  public static String getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat)
    {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
            return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
        }catch (Exception e){
            ExceptionHandler.printStackTrace(e);
        }
        return ""+milliSeconds;
    }


getDate(time, "dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss")
```

hope it may help you